# How to prove that an ideal in the class group is not principal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\theta$ be a root of the polynomial $p=x^3+6x-1$, and $K=\mathbb{Q}\left[\theta\right]$ the field generated by it, and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers with integral basis $\left(1,\theta,\theta^2\right)$. Let $P$ be the principal ideal $\left(3\right)$. Since $p \mod 3 = \left(x-1\right)^3$ we know that $P$ splits as $I^3$, where $I$ is the ideal $\left(3,\theta-1\right)$.
This is an indication that the class $\left[I\right]$ has order $3$, but in order to prove this one has to show that $I$ is not a principal ideal. Practically this results in proving that there doesn't exist an element in $\mathcal{O}_K$ that has norm $3$. In likewise situations in quadratic extensions this is proven by the non-existing solution of a Diophantine equation involving the expression of the norm in function of the coefficients of the elements. But unlike the quadratic case the cubic case doesn't yield a quadratic form. Now what I would like to do is the following:

The norm of the ideal $J=\left(\theta-1\right)$ is $N\left(J\right)=6$,and $N\left(P\right)=3^3$. If the ideal $I$ would be principal it would be generated by an algebraic integer that is $\gcd\left(3,\theta-1\right)$. But is there a way to obtain this value and show that it is not an algebraic integer?

Marc Bogaerts

Comment: Irrelevant, but just to be correct N(I)=-6 and K=Q(\theta)

Comment: How can the norm of an ideal be negative? Isn't the norm simply the number of congruence classes modulo the ideal?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I often confuse the norm of an ideal with the determinant of a matrix formed by the vectors that span the lattice formed by the ideal, this can clearly be negative. But your definition is right, and one should always take abolute values.

Comment: In which field do you expect to find $\mathrm{gcd}(3,\theta-1)$? In quadratic fields, the gcd of the generators of a non-principal ideal is not simply a non-integral element of the field, but rather lives in an extension. Wouldn't that also be the case here? Do we know which extension?

Comment: The field under consideration is $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is a root of $x^3+6x−1$. The main question was how is it  possible to show that $I$ is a principal ideal or not, the $\mathrm{gcd}$ question is in fact irrelevant.

Comment: It seemed like a good idea to me, but I think it would have to be asked in an extension of $K$, because that's how it works in the quadratic case. If, in a quadratic field, you have a non-principal ideal $(\alpha,\beta)$, then $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)$ does exist, and it is an algebraic integer. It just doesn't live in the quadratic field in question, but in some extension. If you knew which extension to work in, maybe you could find the gcd there, and then check whether that value is in $K$, or only in the extension.

Comment: I'm not saying I know how to do that. I've been thinking about this problem, and my strategy right now is to write down a expression for the norm of $\alpha=a+b\theta+c\theta^2$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$, and then see if I can show there are no integer solutions.

Comment: Incidentally, how do you know that $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$ forms an integral basis in this field?

Comment: Ok, this formula seems to be correct: $N(a+b\theta+c\theta^2)=a^3+b^3+c^3+6ab^2+6bc^2+36ac^2-12a^2c-3abc$. I got that using symmetric polynomials. If setting that equal to $3$ yields no integer solutions, then your ideal in non-principal.

Comment: Got it. By checking cases, it turns out that no combination of $a,b,c$ leads to $N(a+b\theta+c\theta^2)\equiv 3\pmod{27}$. Therefore your ideal is non-principal.

Comment: I know  $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$ is an integral basis because I use an algorithm (the brute force kind) that exhausts all possibilties. In this case the "original" basis couldn't be refined.

Comment: Why do you take the norm mod 27?

Comment: Kind of a hunch. I saw all those coefficients that are multiples of 3, so I looked at the norm modulo 9 first, and when that didn't help, I tried it modulo 27. When it worked, I felt a bit lucky.